# How to validate phylogenetic glmm from phyr package?

Tags: r, mixed-models, phylogeny

I have a dataset with 30 plant species, 6 treatments and 5 replicates per sp*trmt combination (n=900). I have measured several traits such as germination %, synchrony, seedlings biomass, etc. I also have a phylogenetic tree including only my 30 species.

I work with R and I want to include phylogeny into my glmm analysis but I've encountered many packages that work only if there's a unique value per species name; this clearly doesn't work for my data, due to the presence of treatments and replicates. Today I've found a recently-released package called phyr, which solves this issue. However, I can't seem to find a way to check the validity of the models created by this package, since it's not supported by DHARMa.

To include unsupported packages, the creator of DHARMa suggests to "create simulations from the fitted model by hand and then read in those simulations into DHARMa for the respective checks" https://github.com/florianhartig/DHARMa/wiki/Adding-new-R-packages-to-DHARMA

However, that is truly beyond my coding abilities, especially since I have different types of models (gaussian, binomial, etc). Does anyone have an idea on how to alternatively validate the models or can provide me with some code to do so?

I would highly appreciate!!